# Replace GString tags in a file

Tags: file, groovy, gstring

i've got a word document saved in xml format. In this document, there are some GString Tag like $name.

In my groovy code, i load the xml file to replace this GString tag like this:

```
    def file = new File ('myDocInXml.xml')
    def name = 'myName'
    file.eachLine { line ->
        println line
    }
```

But it doesn't works. The GString Tag doesn't be replaced by my variable 'name'.

Could anyone help me ?

THX

Comment: gstrings are hot, why would you want to replace one?

Comment: Hello,
I've got some word's document which are saved in xml format. I've replaced some informations by GString Tag like $name, $address, $city...
And i'd like to replace those tags by data which came from my database.
Thank's for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to use a templating here. Load the xmml file as a template and create a binding to replace the placeholders. A simple example could be like

```
def xml='''
<books>
<% names.each { %>
<book>
 $it
</book>
<%}%>

</books>
'''
def engine=new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
def template=engine.createTemplate(xml)
def binding=[names:['john','joe']]
template.make(binding)
```

Comment: Right. The problem is that loading an XML file does not trigger GString evaluation.

Comment: Thank's for your answer !
I create a template with a fileReader open on my xmlFile, and it works now =)
Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

Currently templating is the approach.  But  you might want to keep an eye on this issue in JIRA [GROOVY-2505](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2505).  It is a feature request to convert a String to a GString in cases when the string is read from an external source:

> Several times it has been asked on the
>   mailing list on how to either convert
>   a String to a GString or to evaluate a
>   String as a GString. The need arises
>   when a String comes in from an
>   external source and contains a GString
>   expression, for example an XML file or
>   a Configuration file. Currently one
>   needs to either invoke the GroovyShell
>   or the SimpleTemplateEngine to
>   accomplish the task. In both cases
>   this takes several lines of code and
>   is not intuitively obvious. One could
>   ether add a GDK method to String such
>   as "evaluate" (which in my humble
>   opinion would be the nicest) or
>   provide a conversion of the form
>   "String as GString"

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question, however, issue http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-2505 still not solved...
There is a nice workaround, which behaves almost like GString substitution, by using Apache StrSubstitutor class. For me it is more comfortable than creating templates - you can use GStrings in XML files:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.text.StrSubstitutor

strResTpl = new File(filePath + "example.xml").text

def extraText = "MY EXTRA TEXT"

map = new HashMap();
map.put("text_to_substitute", "example text - ${extraText}")

def result = new StrSubstitutor(map).replace(strResTpl);
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eample>
    <text_to_substitute>${text_to_substitute}</text_to_substitute>
</example>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eample>
    <text_to_substitute>example text - MY EXTRA TEXT</text_to_substitute>
</example>
```